# Firefox throws error for WWW in-url despite redirects

Tags: apache-2.2, ssl-certificate, firefox

I recently installed SSL on a website and set it up so that http(s)://www.my-url.com redirects to https://my-url.com . I confirmed that this is working in Chrome.

Unfortunately, if a Firefox visitor browses to https://www.my-url.com, they get a security warning. This seems to happen only in firefox, so I believe there is some server-side setting I could change to fix this.

Is there a way to circumvent this? I know technically that SSL is established before the redirect happens but it seems to work in every other browser. I'd like to avoid getting a new certificate if possible.

Comment: What is the actual security warning code?

Comment: `Error code: ssl_error_bad_cert_domain`

Comment: Your site isn't responding for me _at all_. Is it up?

Comment: Yes, thats a dummy url.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you have a valid certificate for BOTH domains?
Either two certs with a SNI-aware server, or a single certs for both domains (SAN) should work.
A wildcard cert would NOT work, as it only applies to subdomain level (ie. www1.my-url.com and www2.my-url.com, but not to my-url.com)
Depending on your server setup, the problem could be related to SNI/SAN browser support (nevertheless any updated browser should work) or a "feature" of chrome allowing a wildcard to work on a 2-level domain such as my-url.com.